# Al hacer hover se queda activado el div y no desaparece

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando `jQuery` para hacer **hover** en el botón que activa una caja, la caja aparece... hasta ahí bien, pero no desaparece cuando ya se ha quitado el cursor, cómo puedo solucionar esto?

```js
$('.hover').hover(function(){
  $('.box').css({
    "display": "flex"
  });
});
```

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.box{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="box">
    <h1>HOVER</h1>
</div>

<button class="hover">hover</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el método mouseout:

> $( "#ID" ).mouseout(function(){ });

[Jquery .mouseout()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

Quité el display flex del body y coloqué el botón en un div nada más para separarlos en el ejemplo ya que si lo dejas como está ocurre un problema y es que al pasar el mouse por encima aparece el elemento con el id box y mueve el botón por lo que el mouse deja de estar encima del mismo y por consiguiente desaparece el elemento con el id box. Debes tener eso en cuenta para tu caso.

```js
$('.hover').hover(function(){
  $('.box').css({
    "display": "block"
  });
});

$('.hover').mouseout(function(){
  $('.box').css({
    "display": "none"
  });
});
```

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.box{
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #ddd;
display: none;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button class="hover">hover</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
<h1>HOVER</h1>
</div>
```